# Flutter App is getting crashed when picking multiple images from gallery and displaying on to the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, image-compression

Flutter App is getting crashed when picking multiple images from gallery and displaying on to the screen.
Is there a way to compress the pictures before displaying them? How to compress multiple pictures at a time? Can we display images as thumbnails to load faster and smoother?

I am currently using image picker to pick multiple images and store them in a list. How to compress all the selected pictures in the list and display them without crashing?
Please help me out!

```
List<XFile> picturesList = [];

  pickImages() async {
    try {
      final List<XFile>? pickedImages = await ImagePicker().pickMultiImage();
      if (pickedImages!.isNotEmpty) {
        picturesList.addAll(pickedImages);
        notifyListeners();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
class ImagesGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImagesGrid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              pickImages();
            },
            child: const Text('Pick Images')),
        SizedBox(
          height: 600,
          child: GridView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                childAspectRatio: 1,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                crossAxisCount: 4),
            itemCount: picturesList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: Image.file(
                  File(picturesList[index].path),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use `cached_network_image` package and provide size so that the raw image could be reduced in size.

Comment: Images are loaded from the gallery /  local storage not network?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to pick multiple images from phone internal storage and compressing the selected pictures on the go and displaying.
Used [File picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) instead of Image picker to pick the images and  [Flutter Native Image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image) package to compress the pictures. This is quite faster to load pictures also app isn't crashing even though loading original high resolution pictures as well.

```
class ImagesGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImagesGrid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImagesGrid> createState() => _ImagesGridState();
}

class _ImagesGridState extends State<ImagesGrid> {
  List<String> selectedImages = [];
  List<String> temporaryImages = [];
  List<File> compressedImages = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Compress Images')),
      body: compressedImages.isNotEmpty
          ? Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 700,
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            childAspectRatio: 1,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                            crossAxisCount: 4),
                    itemCount: compressedImages.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        child: Image.file(
                          compressedImages[index],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => pickImages(),
                    child: const Text('Pick Images')),
              ],
            )
          : InkWell(
              onTap: () => pickImages(),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text('Tap anywhere to pick images')
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }

  pickImages() async {
    try {
      final pickedImages = await FilePicker.platform
          .pickFiles(type: FileType.image, allowMultiple: true);
      if (pickedImages != null && pickedImages.files.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {});
        final image = pickedImages.files.map((e) => e.path!);
        selectedImages.addAll(image);
        temporaryImages.addAll(image);

        for (int i = 0; i < temporaryImages.length; i++) {
          compressImage(temporaryImages[i]);
        }

        Future.delayed(
            const Duration(seconds: 1), () => temporaryImages.clear());
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }

  compressImage(path) async {
    if (selectedImages.isEmpty) return;
    ImageProperties properties =
        await FlutterNativeImage.getImageProperties(path);
    await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(path,
            quality: 50,
            targetWidth: 600,
            targetHeight:
                (properties.height! * 600 / (properties.width)!).round())
        .then((response) => setState(() => compressedImages.add(response)))
        .catchError((e) => debugPrint(e));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify quality of images while picking

```dart
try {
          final List<XFile>? pickedFileList = await _picker.pickMultiImage(
             maxHeight: 480, maxWidth: 640
            imageQuality: quality,//<---this will compress the images
          );
          setState(() {
            _imageFileList = pickedFileList;
          });
        } catch (e) {
          setState(() {
            _pickImageError = e;
          });
```

Comment: Already tried using above parameters still app is getting crashed. Pictures I am selecting are 10MB each.

Comment: It should not be from here. Since its in try catch. Did you try picking a smaller single image too?

Comment: Smaller pictures are working fine. Even I'm selecting more than 30 pictures at a time. But when it comes to pictures more than 8MB. App is getting crashed and showing below in the debug console

W/Adreno-GSL(15820): <gsl_ldd_control:553>: ioctl fd 106 code 0xc0300945 (IOCTL_KGSL_GPUOBJ_ALLOC) failed: errno 12 Out of memory
E/Adreno-GSL(15820): <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2604>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
Lost connection to device.
Exited

Comment: This means that your device is having less memory to process these many images at once. so for example you run 10 images of 10 mb so you need a min 100MB to just load them plus memory for compressing *10 then to write.

Comment: What is the solution to this problem? I kept image quality as 1. still app is getting crashed when using 10MB pictures

Comment: Unfortunately there is no solution that I know (sorry if I am wrong) since I believe it works with platform channels. So there won't be a check. Try running it on some other device

Comment: I found the solution to this using Flutter Native Image package and File picker instead of Image picker. Now it is able to compress 10MB picture to 90KB without loosing much the quality.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73391785/18420077